# Sphinx merging command failed: rake ts:merge fails while indexer command succeeds

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

Sphinx: 2.3.2-beta
Thinking Sphinx: 4.4.1

When we run `bundle rake ts:merge INDEX_FILTER=artcile`, we get the following error:

> The Sphinx merging command failed:

> Command:indexer --config "config/sphinx.conf" --merge article_core artcile_delta --merge-dst-range sphinx_deleted 0 0 --rotate

> Status:  2

However, we get a successful merge when we run the same indexer command that TS is trying to run. Any idea why this could be happening?

Note: For certain reasons we are not running searchd, we are only indexing

Comment: Is the rake task being called by the same user? And through an active shell, or via code, or cron, or something else?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, Pat. Yes the same user. And the cron runs a shell script that in turn calls the rake task.

Comment: if `searchd` is not running, the --rotate switch will generally cause the command to fail (because `indexer` can't find the PID file of searchd!). The --rotate switch should only be used when searchd is running. Note when it 'fails' the actual 'merge' has probably actully run! (because only checks for the pid after doing the merge)

Comment: So suppose if we have to merge multiple indices without running the `searchd`, our only option is to directly run the `indexer` command for each index? because `ts:merge` will fail at the first index merge itself and not proceed further?

Comment: I'm curious as to why you're not running `searchd`… I presume some kind of index-syncing process across machines?

Comment: But also: the `--rotate` flag should only be added by Thinking Sphinx if it thinks the daemon is running… the fact that there's no daemon, no pidfile, means it _shouldn't_ have this flag. Don't suppose you've any idea why it is detecting the daemon? 

Comment: Your presumption is right. We are syncing indices across machines.